# Ubuntu iso version for dell inspiron 1150

Tags: system-installation, dell, 10.10

somebody through a dell Inspiron 1150 laptop(2004) with Ubuntu 10.10 on it but it needs a password which i don't have
i tried to install 13.04 but i got an internal error message saying

```
executablepath
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test
```

than i tried to download the 10.10 version but when i turned on with the burned cd inside  it didn't work 
I'll be happy if someone could help and would like to help me.

Comment: Your question is about Ubuntu 10.10 which makes it off-topic here (support for 10.10 ended >1yr ago). I think what you really need help with is the duplicate from my above comment. Try a newer version and just wipe the old install, using the entire drive. If your goal is to recover data from the 10.10 install, then please try a search here or post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Inspiron 1150 has following specification: (http://www.cnet.com/laptops/dell-inspiron-1150/4507-3121_7-30836485.html), Intel Celeron 2.5GHz, Intel Extreme Graphics 2 - max 64.0 MB shared memory, Max 2GB RAM.

Ubuntu with Unity desktop probably will not work as the Intel graphics card don't have all necessary 3D functions (Intel 852 / 855 chip-sets). Try to disable 3D in BIOS set-up and try again, not sure if this is the option. If not try to upgrade the BIOS to its latest version. Due to your hardware I don't recommend to use Unity desktop anyway.

For Inspiron 1150 I recommend to use Xubuntu (with xfce desktop http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or Lubuntu (with lxde desktop http://www.lubuntu.net/), which have lower demands to the hardware set-up, but they does not have Unity. Your Ubuntu 10.10 does not have Unity either, but uses Gnome desktop. You will need 32bit installation. Try the live version first to be sure it will work.

And please upgrade ram to its max (2GB). This will help the computer to bear 12.04 or 13.04 version of Xubuntu/Lubuntu.